# Seting User Agent param in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, facebook, parsing

Is there any way to include the user agent string along with the request send by PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the code it should be possible by using context streams, something like:

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => 'UserAgent/1.0'));
file_get_html('http://www.google.com/', 0, $context);
```

Alternatively you can also set default value in [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent).

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Michal Čihař, you are right
I just made some changes in the load_file() function of simple_html_dom class and it worked

```
// load html from file
    function load_file() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        // Added by Mithun
        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "User-Agent:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6\r\n".
                "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $args[1] = FALSE;
        $args[2] = $context;
        // End Mithun
        $this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    }
```

Comment: HI Mithun, I require your help. How can i contact you

Comment: did you remove the last lines : // Throw an error if we can't properly load the dom.
  if (($error=error_get_last())!==null) {
   $this->clear();
   return false;
  }
 }