# PHP simple_html_dom load_file with user agent

Tags: php, user-agent, simple-html-dom

I need to crawl a web site with simple_dom_html->load_file(),and i need include a user agent,follow is my code,but  i don't know if my code is right or there has a good way to achieve my needs.thanks in advance

`$option = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
            )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($option);
    $simple_html_dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $simple_html_dom -> load_file(CRAWLER_URL, false, $context);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945511/seting-user-agent-param-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your method / code and I can confirm it works as intended: the user-agent in the HTTP header send, is correctly changed to the one you provide with the code. :-)

As for your uncertainty: I usually use the curl functions to obtain the HTML string (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php). In this way I have more control of the HTTP request and then (when anything works fine) I use the `simple_dom_html→str_get_html()` function on the HTML string I get with curl. So I am more flexible in error handling, dealing with redirects and I had implemented some caching...

The solution for your problem was simply to grep a URL like http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ and lock in the result for the user-agent string used in the request, to check if it had worked as intended...

Comment: I have read the code of function simple_html_dom -> load_file() this afternoon,and i also think i am right, now have your confirmation,i am sure i am right,thanks.